# Why can't i deploy update a prepopulated database?

Tags: .net, sqlite, deployment, maui

I have an embedded prepopulated sqlite database to deploy with my app. After editing the database I'm now getting very strange results when attempting to deploy/update to an Android phone using stream copy. My code checks if the file exist so normally I don't continually overwrite. I can comment out this code to perform a forced overwrite with the new database and it appears on the phone perfectly fine.

Next If I uncomment the file exist code and deploy a second time so stopping the embed file overwriting again then the old database reappears. I have tried adding a file.delete() command in to make sure the old database is removed from the phone before updating but the problem persists. Frankly I'm baffled!

This is my code.

If I comment out the If file exist part the database overwrites and all good. If I then go back and include the file.exist part back comes the old database. I have tried making sure the old file is deleted off the phone before update by using the File.Delete(). I have uninstalled the app and power cycled the phone. I've updated Nuget packages, Rebuilt solution and rebuilt the app. I have no idea where it is finding the old database and there are no old copies in my project.

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
  Assembly assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
  
  using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MrDiver.Port.db3"))
  {
      using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
        if (File.Exists(PortDatabase.DBPath))   //checks if the database exists and stops the copy

             // File.Delete(PortDatabase.DBPath);     //Used for database update to delete old database
              return;

          stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        
          File.WriteAllBytes(PortDatabase.DBPath, memoryStream.ToArray());
      }

  }
```

UPDATE - I've resolved the issue but will leave this here in case anyone else hits the same snag. I tried another Android phone and it worked perfectly as expected which led me to accuse the first phone as the problem. I did a factory reset on the phone and all came good.

Comment: You may need to comment out the If file exist part. Also, you can refer to this sample:https://github.com/jfversluis/ExistingSQLiteDbSample/blob/main/ExistingSQLiteDbSample/ExistingSQLiteDbSample/MainPage.xaml.cs